# Callback doesn't compile (wrong number of parameters specified

Tags: callback, windows-ce, lazarus

I'm trying to call a function in a dll on a WinCE system.
this are the defines

```
type
  TPREVIEW_CALLBACK = procedure ( pData: PByte; len: long; height: Integer; width: Integer; stride: Integer) of object; cdecl;
  PPREVIEW_CALLBACK = ^TPREVIEW_CALLBACK;
  function camRegisterPreviewCallback(PreviewCallbackProc: PPREVIEW_CALLBACK): Integer; cdecl; external 'CameraAPI.dll';
```

I made all functions global, this is the callback (still empty)

```
procedure PreviewCallback(pData: PByte; len: long; height: Integer; width: Integer; stride: Integer);
begin
end;
```

The call (also in a global function) is

```
CamRegisterPreviewCallback(PreviewCallback);
```

The error during compilation I get is
Error: Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "PreviewCallback"
As far as I understand it the parameter is a pointer so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks in advance
Herman

Comment: First of all you are missed `of object; cdecl;` in the `TPREVIEW_CALLBACK` declaration so your callback procedure must be a class method with `cdecl`directive. Next, `CamRegisterPreviewCallback(@PreviewCallback);` where `@` signs that it is a pointer to the method, not the calling of it.

Comment: Isn't the of object only needed when it's a function within a class? In my case I made all global functions. I changed the declaration to function camRegisterPreviewCallback(PreviewCallbackProc: TPREVIEW_CALLBACK): Integer; cdecl; external 'CameraAPI.dll'; (not PPre.... but TPrev....) together with the proposed @ now it compiles and seems to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you write using the FPC dialect (`{$MODE OBJFPC}`) a function pointer must be explicitly specified using the `@` symbol.

Without this the compiler thinks that you want to call the function rather than to take its address.

So rewrite the last line as

```
CamRegisterPreviewCallback(@PreviewCallback);
```

By the way, as noted by someone in a comment, verify well your `TPREVIEW_CALLBACK` prototype. You declare its as `of object` but you implement it as a global function, which is an error. `of object` really means that the method has to be implemented in an class. The procedural variable of an object method is not the same as a procedural variable of a free function. In the first case there is an additional context pointer (the `Self`), so both are totally incompatible !

If the dll is written in C it's very likely that the `of object` is superfluous, but unfortunatly it's hard to say without the library API documentation.

Comment: Thanks, About the of object, I knew but the other I didn't. About the superfluous part, I could do some tests but it remains superfluous.